# how to take the part of a string

Tags: c#, string, methods, split, windows-phone

how i can take a part of this string :

```
string="<ArrayOfArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring xmlns:d1p1="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" i:type="d1p1:base64Binary" xmlns:i="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/Arrays">0RuHA6OkPMP7myQPAR4ZDMoB8mo=</ArrayOfArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>";
```

i need to take just this part "0RuHA6OkPMP7myQPAR4ZDMoB8mo" , how can i programmaticaly divide the part i need?

its not an xml its the string the system give me back when i ask details of the telephone, i need to get only the part of the IMEI:

```
 Object obj = DeviceExtendedProperties.GetValue("DeviceUniqueId");
 byte[] objByte = ObjectToByteArray(obj);
 IMEI = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(objByte, 0, objByte.Length);
```

this the ObjectToByteArray():

```
 private byte[] ObjectToByteArray(Object obj)
        {
            DataContractSerializer serializer = new DataContractSerializer(typeof(List<Dictionary<String, String>>));

            byte[] byteArr;

            using (var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream())
            {
                serializer.WriteObject(ms, obj);
                byteArr = ms.ToArray();
            }
            return byteArr;
```

i cut the string using Split and Replace by this way:

```
 a1 = IMEI.Split(IMEIerrato, 2 ,StringSplitOptions.None);
 IMEIgiusto = a1[1].Replace("=</ArrayOfArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>", "");
 Debug.WriteLine("IMEI: "+IMEIgiusto);
```

i get this output:

```
IMEI: 0RuHA6OkPMP7myQPAR4ZDMoB8mo
```

RESOLVED

Comment: If it's XML, why not use an XML API?

Comment: @JonSkeet its not an xml

Comment: It certainly looks like XML to me. In what way do you believe that's not XML?

Comment: its the return i get from IMEI = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(objByte, 0, objByte.Length);

Comment: Sure. That doesn't mean it's not XML... (Are you sure that `obj` isn't already a string when you fetch it, by the way? What is the `ObjectToByteArray` method?)

Comment: so the .GetValue() give me back an xml object? i can parse it whit xml api? whitout put it into a array?

Comment: I don't know - you can easily find out for yourself though; just look at the value in the debugger. Again, we still don't know what your `ObjectToByteArray` method does. But my answer shows how you can easily extract the value out of the string you've given here...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'd use an XML API:

```
XElement element = XElement.Parse(text);
string value = element.Value;
byte[] bytes = Convert.FromBase64String(value);
```

Answer (score 0):

i cut the string using Split and Replace by this way:

```
 a1 = IMEI.Split(IMEIerrato, 2 ,StringSplitOptions.None);
 IMEIgiusto = a1[1].Replace("=</ArrayOfArrayOfKeyValueOfstringstring>", "");
 Debug.WriteLine("IMEI: "+IMEIgiusto);
```

i get this output:

```
IMEI: 0RuHA6OkPMP7myQPAR4ZDMoB8mo
```